# Make a chainable jQuery Plugin that filters a collection using another jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, performance, chaining

What I am trying to do is fairly specific. I have a plugin that returns true/false if an item is within the viewport +/- a tolerance amount. I am trying to write a plug-in that can be passed a collection and will then filter that collection down to only those elements which are in the viewport. Further I want this to be able to chained in the normal way, so called like $('.someSelector').inViewport().css('color', 'green'); which would make all the selected elements that are also in the viewport green.

The viewport detecting code works its the mechanics of creating the chainable plugin inViewport() (the 2cd one) that I am looking for advice on. The issue is that I am expecting the collection to be filtered but I am getting the whole collection instead.

I am also interested to get feedback on ways I could code this so its efficient processor wise as I will have to run these methods on many elements at a relatively high frequency.

Any advice is appreciated.

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function(){

var tolerance = 600;
var win = $(window);

var viewport = {
    top : win.scrollTop(),
    left : win.scrollLeft()
};

viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width() + tolerance;
viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height() + tolerance;

var bounds = this.offset();
bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};
```

//this is the one thats not working quite right

```
$.fn.inViewport = function(){

console.log('what is this?');
console.dir(this);

this.filter(function(idx) {
 console.log('////////////////////////////////');
 console.dir($(this));
 console.log($(this).isInViewport());
 return $(this).isInViewport();
});

console.log('what is this AFTER?');
console.dir(this); //it should be filtered but its not

return this;

};

//I am calling it something like this
        $('.galleryImage').inViewport().children('imageContentContainer').find('.img').someOtherJqueryFunction()
```

So thanks to Kalley in the comments - I see that I wasn't storing/returning the value of the filtered array. The resulting code looks like:

```
$.fn.inViewport = function(){

return this.filter(function(idx) {
 return $(this).isInViewport();
});

};
```

Comment: I think you need to return `this.filter` or the result of `this.filter`.

Comment: Thanks - thats the ticket. I was assuming .filter would alter the original array so I wasn't storing the result.